# Best way to receive large amount of data from serial port in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am currently working on a project where I have to receive 128 MB of data from the serial port. I have PCB where there is 128MB FLASH and a Microcontroller on it. I connected a FTDI board from microcontroller to my PC. My basic algorithms work like this:

1. I send Address I want to read (at start 0x00000000) to microcontroller with preambles and stuff:
2. Microcontroller reads 256 Bytes from FLASH and transmits through Serial channel.
3. Received data is written to a text file.
4. Increment memory 256 bytes then send address again.

Basically that's it.

On my PC I wrote simple program in C# that configures and opens the port of serial channel then transmit address when I click the button.

However, I have noticed that some of the data is wrong. For example I got 0x09 0x00 instead of 0x09 0xcf. Some of the data are zeros.

pseudo code is below:

```
while (Page < End_Of_Memory)
{
    SerialPort.Write(Command_n_PageAddress);
    SerialPort.Read(InputBuffer,0,256);
    Stream.Write(MyTxtFile.txt,0,256);
    Page++;
}
```

Baudrate of Serial Channel = 2Mbps

Why am I receiving 0x00 sometimes? Also is this the correct way to read from serial port? Should I wait for some time so that data transmission is complete and then read the buffer? What else can I do to make sure the correct data is received when dealing with this much of data(Maybe simple checksum)?

Comment: Check return value of SerialPort.Read - it returns the number of bytes actually read - it may be not 256 and depends on how controller behaves. And a small delay between write and read also may help.

Comment: The addressing mode is different.  Intel format the order of an address is 1,0,3,2 where zero is the lsb and 3 is the msb.  Smart cards has different modes that can be for address 64,32,16,8 and data 64,32,16,8.  So you have to make sure the c# code works properly with the card you are using.

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean by address?

Comment: Can I use the return value to poll the number of bytes that is received? Like wait until 256 bytes received? while(SerialPort.Read(InputBuffer,0,256) == 256); @Quercus

Comment: When sending/receiving serial data you need to wait until the entire data block is received so you need to know where the end of the block occurs.  So you can use one of three methods 1) Add a character at end of each block that is not part of the message 2) Add a byte count at beginning of the message 3) Use Fix size messages.  You also may have an issue with the way the data is being sent.  The order of the data may not be from MSB to LSB (or LSB to MSB).  Depending on the type of card and the software that is sending the serial data will determine the format of the data.

Comment: @jdweng I am using fixed size message, the order of MSB LSB is right. I am getting correct message. My problem is sometimes I am receiving 0x00 or I am missing some data so when I read receive buffer for 256 bytes I am getting 0x00 at ending of data frame.

Comment: There is no guarantee you will receive all the data in one chunk.  UART in a PC uses timers to if you send 256 bytes you may occasionally receive only some of the data and then you need to read again to get the rest.  So simplest solution is to add a while loop around the read and if you do not get 256 bytes read again.